# sed, grep, and awk file sorting

Tags: command-line, grep, documentation, sed, awk

I'm trying to get all the files which have 'load' in their names from a directory.
I'm trying to do:

```
find -type f | sed -s 'load
```

However, I recurrently receive an error

sed: -e expression #1, char 1: unknown command: `f'

A worse part is that although I am able to manipulate regexes I 'm really bad at using grep/sed/awk, and this is slowing me down all the time.  Whatever material I found online so far isn't great. Do you guys have any know of any comprehensive and fairly concise screencasts/tutorials?  I still miss the skill to read and quickly understand linux manuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need grep/sed/awk at all, let `find` filter the results for you:

```
find . -type f -name '*load*'
```

Or, in bash only

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob
load_files=( **/*load* )
```

if you do want an external tool:

```
find . -type f | grep load
find . -type f | awk '/load/'
find . -type f | sed -n '/load/p'
```

With the sed, use -n to suppress normal output, and only print for lines matching the pattern.